# referenceerror treasureHunter not defined?

Tags: javascript

so i was programming a javascript program, and for some reason, i got an error saying: ReferenceError: treasureHunter not defined
I searched all over the internet for this info, but although this has been answered many times, their answers don't fit specifically to the problem in the code.
Here's the code:

```
// Sets a global variable for loot. Global variables exist outside functions or conditional statements. Local variables exist within those things.
global loot = 0;
// alert(loot);
// Creates a function called treasureHunter(). We don't put anything in the parenthesis, but we will later for other functions.
function treasureHunter() {
//Creates a local variable inside treasureHunter called treasureSuccess equal to Math.random(). Math.random is bult into JavaScript, and creates a random number between 0 and 1, e.g. .456 or .99. We use this to create excitement in an otherwise dull and boring existence.
var treasureSuccess = Math.random();
//Here we create a local variable called closedChest equal to the image that we want to pull down from the interwebs when we fail at getting loot. 

var closedChest = "<img src='https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/eb/c7/84/ebc784ae55857b1470767c4747eb0715.jpg' length='285px' width='285px'>";
//Here we create a local variable called openChest equal to the image that we want to call up when we succeed - YES!
var openChest = "<img src='https://slm-assets1.secondlife.com/assets/1545906/lightbox/e6cfd0355756301c0f6f6d666e75c3de.jpg?1277247329' length='285px' width='285px'>";
var dragon = "<img src='http://orig06.deviantart.net/dd94/f/2012/112/c/b/cb9da88db9660edea4746e95df8fa4ed-d4x7orn.jpg' length='285px' width='285px'>";
//Here we create a conditional statement that asks if the variable treasureSuccess is greater than 5. This is called a boolean operation, it can be answered yes or no. This will of course be random, since treasureSuccess is equal to Math.random() - see above. 
if (treasureSuccess > .5) {
//Here we tell the conditional statement what to do if it evaluates true, in other words, if Math.random() happens to be greater than .5. This will change the element using treasureChest, our DIV above in our HTML to the openChest variable, which is set to the image of an open chest. Go figure :) 
if (treasureSuccess > .9) {
//dragon time!!
document.getElementById("TreasureChest").innerHTML = dragon;
//dragon image
loot = 0;
//loot reset
document.getElementById("Loot").innerHTML = "You lost all your gold!";
}
}
else {
document.getElementById("TreasureChest").innerHTML = openChest;
//This adds 100 to the global variable loot, each time we are successful, or each time treasureSuccess is greater than .5
loot = loot + 100;
//This tells the loot ID selector to update, so we can see how much gold we've got. THis uses the updated value for loot, which is why it is written below the loot = loot +100 line.
document.getElementById("Loot").innerHTML = "You've got" + " " + loot + " " + " gold";
//waits 500 milliseconds
setTimeout(treasureHunter,500);
document.getElementById("TreasureChest").innerHTML = closedChest;
//reputs the picture
}
//this is the end of the conditional statement
//This tells the statement what to do if the conditional statement evaluates to false, or if treasureSuccess is less than .5. You get a chest slammed shut in your face son. 
else document.getElementById("TreasureChest").innerHTML = closedChest;
}
//this is the end of the function

I call it like this:

<div onclick="treasureHunter()" align="center" id="TreasureChest">
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/eb/c7/84/ebc784ae55857b1470767c4747eb0715.jpg" length="285px" width="285px">
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but this problem happens when i click the button.

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors, so `treasureHunter()` wasn't defined.

- `global` in `global loot = 0;` doesn't seem valid. Change it to `var` or something.
- `else` in `else document.getElementById("TreasureChest").innerHTML = closedChest;` is invalid since there are no corresponding `if`. Remove it or fix the code properly.